# Did God really create the world in six days?

Tags: genesis

According to a well-known biblical tale from Genesis told to me when I was a child, God created the world in six days, then took a rest on the seventh day. Now that I am an adult, I can't help wondering what this six days even means. What does 'time' mean to someone like God? How long were those six days if there is no way for anyone to measure it? Also, time is defined in terms of physical processes which are regular, e.g. the current definition physicists use is

> The second is the duration of 9 192 631 770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the cesium 133 atom.

It seems to me that time not only can't be measured, but has no meaning before the universe was created. How should we interpret this tale of creation?

Comment: God must, of necessity, condescend to our timeliness in order to communicate with us, and we should not assume that this is somehow impossible for the Creator of time.  Also, this question is probably not appropriate for this forum.  There are Christians who will answer quite differently on this topic.  It is also a truth question, which is also not appropriate here.  If you restricted the question to a particular tradition, perhaps Young Earth Creationists, and ask how they explain this, that would be better.

Comment: I'm not looking for truth with a capital T here. Being raised a Catholic, I just never received an answer that made any sense. I was hoping people skilled in theology can answer what I perceive to be a legitimate question and give their views on how this tale is to be interpreted.

Comment: I completely understand, and that is why the question needs to be reworded.

Comment: I like the answers to this question.  Early man would not have been able to comprehend billions of years, so they may have just tried to explain it as best as they could (in days).

Comment: @user1477388 What exactly about the number "billion" makes you think it is less comprehensible than any lesser number? Or more easily comprehensible that any greater number? Would you say you understand the concept of a googolplex? Basic mathematics is all it takes. And "billion" is just counting. To say someone can't comprehend a simple number is to say they can't even count. It's ridiculous. [Ancient Egyptian had a symbol for million and infinity.](http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/numbers/egypt/intro.htm) That's not too far off from a billion.

Comment: @fredsbend you think early man would have known that the Earth upon which they stood was billions of years old?  Something we modern day humans have only discovered in the last 50 years Ref. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_the_Earth

Comment: @user1477388 You didn't challenge their knowledge of that. You challenged their ability to even understand the number billion. You said "Early man would not have been able to comprehend billions of years." And why is that so exactly? What about early man (circa 2000 BC as an early and very rough date for the writing of Genesis) makes you think they were incapable of comprehending that number?

Comment: @fredsbend Well I meant to say that they would not have been able to comprehend that the Earth could have been so old (because we, ourselves, have only recently come to that conclusion via modern scientific methods). Although, whether or not they could comprehend the number itself - I don't know if there would have been any such circumstances where such a number would have been applicable, so I doubt it would be a widely understood concept among such primitive people. But I could be wrong - I don't really care :)

Comment: @user1477388 Hinduism accounts for much longer than 4 billion years. That's also the oldest religion. Thinking the Earth is very, very ancient is not a new thing. Scientifically measuring things to deduce an age for the Earth is, but that is an entirely different and unrelated thing.

Comment: @fredsbend Didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting the creation tale as literal 6 days, here are some facts.

The Hebrew calendar is a  [lunisolar calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunisolar_calendar), meaning that months are based on lunar months, but years are based on solar years. A day in [Hebrew calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Day) is counted from sunset to the next sunset. Sunset is the starting point for a new day but night time is considered as the transition period between the two days , therefore, morning (sunrise) is mostly called as the start of a day.

> Genesis 1:1-5 (NIV)  In the beginning God created the heavens and the
>   earth. Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the
>   surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the
>   waters. And God said, “***Let there be light***,” and there was light.
>   God saw that the light was good, and he separated the light from the
>   darkness. God called the light “day” and the darkness he called
>   “night.” And ***there was evening, and there was morning***—the first
>   day.

As we see in Genesis 1:3-5, **light was the first thing that God created**, which means that the sun was the first creation. **This made it possible to start counting the time based on the sun.** That is why the creation of the sun (light) was marked as the first day, and literally, **the first day on this earth**. Here we have to remember that the earth itself was already there but it was without light. The creation of light could also mean that the sun was already there but was not visible from earth. Therefore, the moment there was light on the surface of the earth, the counting of time based on the sun was also started. **On the first day, the sun might not be clearly visible yet from the earth but the sunlight could penetrate the atmosphere and it was possible to start counting the days based on evening and morning.** God is not controlled by any time measurement but since the book of Genesis was written for human and since it is about the creation of this world, it is more likely that human time measurement was used for narrating the creation story.

> Genesis 1:31 (NIV) God saw all that he had made, and it was very good.
>   And there was evening, and there was morning—the sixth day.

After creating the sun, God continued to create land, animals and lastly, human. God finished his work on the sixth day, which is here again counted based on evening and morning.

If we take the scripture literally as it is, then we can say that God created the world in six days.

Comment: the sun was not created until later in the creation week

Comment: IMO, it sounds to me more like a bunch of epicycles

Comment: @warren That depends on how you interpret it. Though "greater light" is mentioned on the fourth day, I cannot simply assert that it was the sun. What if the sun was created on the first day or prior to it? The fourth day simply was a greater light, which could mean that the sun became clearly visible on the fourth day, though it was already there.

Comment: @Mawia - the greater light was created to rule the day and the lesser to rule the night. What other light could it be referring to?

Answer (score 0):

"How should we interpret this tale of creation?"

THIS WAY (Catholic perspective) : God created the world. It was a purposeful creation, both the world and Man. Not an accident. The world and man has a purpose in the eyes of god.  That is the essential message.

Do not look to the Genesis for historical events. These are myths of profound truth. They are meant to tell us essential information about US, about man. It is inconsequential what the "day" actually means. On the other hand, it is important that world was created in logical manner and genesis could very well be a figurative description of the actual development of the cosmos. Still, was day = 1 day, a millennia or a fraction of a second, not really what Genesis's account of creation is concerned with

Comment: Without sourcing your directives, this comes off as presenting personal opinion as truth. There are a great many Christians who ***DO*** "look to the Genesis for historical events" [sic], Jesus being one of them

Comment: some catholics would agree with the initial statement you made. However, no one disagrees that Genesis is not an account of Jesus: as a man, He did not come to be for another 4000 years. However, I have heard **NO ONE** ever claim that the gospels are "NOT historical accounts" - that is precisely what they are.

Comment: @warren to clarify - what I said before was misleading as I was not choosing my words carefully so previous comments deleted. So, this was a catholic perspective as I understand it, not my opinion. Genesis is not history or historical but mythical. Gospels, as not "history" in strict sense but are a historical accounts of historical event but with primary purpose of proclaiming the good news so are not "history", in the sense that they may not, for example, show accurate chronology.

Comment: that's still not a universal catholic perspective: the synoptic gospels (at the least), along with Genesis through Esther, Job, Acts, and others are all presented as historical narrative. Deciding they are not merely because it doesn't fit with a preconceived notion is dangerous.

Comment: @warren well, there are few "universal" catholic perspectives. Catechism speaks remarkable little on such questions. However, if you believe that the Pope speaks for the Catholic Church, then JPII very clearly look at genesis as mythical. 
"Deciding they are not merely because it doesn't fit with a preconceived notion is dangerous." - Agreed.